# Set Selected Items multi-select drop-down in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to set the selected Items that came from the Cookie that separated of ","  to the multi select bootstrap drop-down list .
that's my Code and I have this Error.

```
Dim lst As List(Of UserSurvey)

Dim SelectedProperties = CookiesManager.GetSubCookieValue("TokenSelections", "TokenProperties").ToString()
If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SelectedProperties)) Then
   lst = SmrService.GetUserSurvey(UserData.UserToken, ddlCompanies.SelectedValue, SelectedProperties, language).ToList()
   ddlSurveys.DataSource = lst
   ddlSurveys.DataValueField = "ID"
   ddlSurveys.DataTextField = "Name"
   ddlSurveys.DataBind()
   Dim myarray As Array = Split(CookiesManager.GetSubCookieValue("TokenSelections", "TokenSurveys").ToString(), ",")
   For Each item As String In myarray
       ddlSurveys.Items.FindByValue(item).Selected = True
   Next
   'For i As Integer = 0 To lst.Count - 1
   '    ddlSurveys.Items.FindByValue(lst(i).ID.ToString()).Selected = True
   'Next
        'ddlSurveys.Items.FindByValue(CookiesManager.GetSubCookieValue("TokenSelections", "TokenSurveys").ToString()).Selected = True
        ' ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "JSCode", "BootstrapDDLManager.selectDefaults('ddlSurveys', RDCookiesManager.getSubCookie('TokenSelections', 'TokenSurveys').split(','))();", True)
    End If
```

and the error :
Stack empty.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: On what line you get have the error?

Comment: @TSion.D.P Dim myarray As Array = Split(CookiesManager.GetSubCookieValue("TokenSelections", "TokenSurveys").ToString(), ",")
   For Each item As String In myarray
       ddlSurveys.Items.FindByValue(item).Selected = True
   Next

Comment: Your array (myarray) is empty..